# How do I implement the functionality of changing players?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a game of basketball with two teams each with 3 players in them. They get 3 shots each, with 1 and 2 pointers if they make it, and 0 if they fail to make it. If any one of the player misses the shot and scores 0 which of course is generated by the random function, the player is changed and the next player comes to play. In this process keep track of individual player scores and also the total score. After all the players have played the next team plays and the same follows for the next team too.
I tried changing the players when they score 0 but since I am new to typescript I cant figure out how I can do it in the following code.

```
class Basketball{
    teams:Array<Team>=[];;
    playing_team:Team;
    constructor(){
        for (let index = 0; index < 2; index++) {
            this.teams.push(new Teams(index));   
        }
        this.playing_team=this.teams[0];
    }
}
```

This is a Basketball class which is the overall game. The constructor here creates two teams.

```
class Teams{
    team_id:number;
    players:Array<Players>=[];
    static team_score:number=0;
    current_player:Players;
    constructor(team_id:number){
        this.team_id=team_id;
        for(let i=0;i<3;i++){
            this.players.push(new Players(i));
        }
        this.current_player=this.players[0];
    }
}
```

This is a teams class where 3 different players are created.

```
class Players{
    player_id:number;
    individual_score:number=0;
    ball_index:number=0;
    all_balls:Array<number>=[null,null,null];

    constructor(id:number){
        this.player_id=id;
    }



    //score baskets
    ballScore(){
        let score=Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
        this.all_balls[this.ball_index]=score;
        this.individual_score +=score;
        Team.team_score +=score;
        this.ball_index++;
        
    }


}
```

This is a players class where each player's scores are tracked. the ball_index is to keep track of which ball he is playing.
The all_balls is the array that stores the score for the each shot he makes. If at 2nd ball he scores 0, then the other player comes and plays his game meaning the first player's 3rd score would be nothing coz he wouldnt be playing that as he scored 0 on the second. Hence, the third value would be null for him.

ballScore is just a function that I have called from html file when I click the button. I just need to know how I could change the players and later change the team too. Thank you.

Also, one more thing, is static keyword the only way we could access variables and methods of other classes without instantiating it in javascript?

Comment: Please consider modifying the code here to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/qNBodm) which demonstrates the issue you're facing and *only* the issue you're facing.  So, correct any typos or unrelated compiler errors or unrelated logic errors (do you really want `this.ball_index++` to walk off the end of the `all_balls` array? Why do you want `null` in there?)  My guess for your question is that you need each player to have a reference to the team it's a part of, but without a good [mcve] it's not clear to me.

Comment: I could imagine answering with code like [this](https://tsplay.dev/ymAo1w), but with the huge caveat that this does not implement whatever actual rules you have for changing players, and does not attempt to make the basketball game proceed according to whatever your requirements are... those are outside the scope of this question.  The important bit is that each `Player` has a reference to the `Team` it is a part of, so that the `Player` can call `this.team.nextPlayer()`.  Does that work for you?  If not, please edit the code here to be a [mcve] and elaborate. If so, I'll write it up.

Comment: Alright that solves it, thank you.